# Files are not being moved using NSFileManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am trying to use NSFileManager to move a file from the Documents/Inbox folder to the Documents folder. I used breakpoints to figure out where my code wasn't working, and everything seemed to be running fine until it hit the part where it actually moves the files. The directories are found and the files are noted in the debugger, but it just won't move. Here is my entire viewDidLoad method (there's nothing in `[super viewDidLoad];`):

```
//Turn every file inside the directory into an array
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appFolderPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *inboxAppFolderPath = [appFolderPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Inbox"]; //changes the directory address to make it for the inbox

//NSPredicates to filter out files I don't want in my NSArray
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF beginswith[c] '.DS_Store'"];
NSPredicate *inboxPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF beginswith[c] 'Inbox'"];
recipes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:appFolderPath error:nil];
recipes = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
recipes = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:inboxPredicate];




//get to inbox directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *inboxContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:inboxAppFolderPath,documentsDirectory] error:nil];

//move all the files over
for (int i = 0; i != [inboxContents count]; i++)
{
    NSString *oldPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:inboxAppFolderPath, documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:appFolderPath, documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];
}
```

Comment: two things to look at: moveItemAtPath returns a bool, have you checked its return value? Also, have you tried passing in an NSError object (instead of nil) to see what error might be occurring?

Comment: I added an NSError, and changed the code for the moving of files to ``BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];``, then added an if statement to check on the error. I got the error "Error removing file at path: (null)", and that's it.

Comment: Could you NSLog the values of `oldPath` and `newPath` immediately before the `moveItemAtPath` call and add some examples to the question? Sometimes it helps to see exactly what we're dealing with.

Comment: @Thunk oldPath = ``/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4308BE72-79FB-4237-8BB8-7F1E513464C1/data/Containers/Data/Application/099DC9F2-0EF4-4FC2-8FAC-37C14173A350/Documents/Inbox`` and newPath = ``/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4308BE72-79FB-4237-8BB8-7F1E513464C1/data/Containers/Data/Application/099DC9F2-0EF4-4FC2-8FAC-37C14173A350/Documents``

Answer (score 0):

There may be issue for creating sub folder inside Documents.

Try to create **inboxAppFolder** in this manner.

```
NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

NSString *inboxAppFolderPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];  // subDirectory

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: inboxAppFolderPath])
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath: inboxAppFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

//Rest of your code
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: I already had the directory created from before, but I added the code anyway for future reference, and to avoid such problems with the app in the future. Thank you for your efforts!